# Printing out char array, a tab takes up 3 spaces

Tags: c, file, fopen, fgets

I have the following data.txt file that I am reading:

```
b    1
b    2
b    3
b    4
```

It is a tab in-between

I have the following code to print it out, line by line, then character by character.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int printCharArray(char *arr);

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    FILE * filePointer;
    filePointer = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    char singleLine[32]; 

    while(!feof(filePointer)){
        fgets(singleLine, 32, filePointer);
        printCharArray(singleLine);
    }

    fclose(filePointer);
    return 0;
}

int printCharArray(char *arr){
    int length = 5;
    printf("\n");

    int i = 0;
    for(i=0;i<length;++i){
        printf("%c, ", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("DONE PRINTING \n");

    return 0;
}
```

What confuses me is what it prints out:

```
b,  ,  ,  , 1, DONE PRINTING 

b,  ,  ,  , 2, DONE PRINTING 

b,  ,  ,  , 3, DONE PRINTING 

b,  ,  ,  , 4, DONE PRINTING
```

I don't understand what there are 3 spaces between the letter and the number. If they're all chars, shouldn't there just be one space for the tab, and that's it?

Comment: Make sure that you really have tabs in data.txt and not spaces...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29476556/read-files-separated-by-tab-in-c this can be helpful..

Comment: @SisterFister I pressed tab when I made the file

Comment: [`while (!feof(file))` is always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong)

Comment: @JamesMitchell Your editor probably converted your tabs to spaces.

Comment: Your output says that the input file does not contain what you think it contains.  In fact, you should use a hex dump program or equivalent to show what's in the file.  You're making some dubious assumptions about line lengths in the function.  (You could modify the printing to: `printf("(%d) %c, ", arr[i],  arr[i]);` to see what the numeric character values are.)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a cleaned up minimal adaptation of your code, with better printing as suggested in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46396995/printing-out-char-array-a-tab-takes-up-3-spaces#comment79751202_46396995).

#### Code

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printCharArray(char *arr);

int main(void)
{
    char filename[] = "data.txt";
    FILE *filePointer = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (filePointer == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file '%s' for reading\b", filename);
        return(1);
    }

    char singleLine[32];

    while (fgets(singleLine, sizeof(singleLine), filePointer) != 0)
        printCharArray(singleLine);

    fclose(filePointer);
    return 0;
}

void printCharArray(char *arr)
{
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; arr[i] != '\0'; ++i)
        printf("(%d) %c, ", arr[i], arr[i]);
    printf("DONE PRINTING\n");
}
```

Here are the outputs from two versions of the data file, one with tabs as claimed and one with spaces.

#### Spaces

Note that the data was copied from the question.  There are 4 spaces between the letter and the digit.  The code also prints the newline; it would be easy to modify it to stop on newline or null byte.

```
(98) b, (32)  , (32)  , (32)  , (32)  , (49) 1, (10) 
, DONE PRINTING

(98) b, (32)  , (32)  , (32)  , (32)  , (50) 2, (10) 
, DONE PRINTING

(98) b, (32)  , (32)  , (32)  , (32)  , (51) 3, (10) 
, DONE PRINTING

(98) b, (32)  , (32)  , (32)  , (32)  , (52) 4, (10) 
, DONE PRINTING
```

#### Tabs

```
(98) b, (9)     , (49) 1, (10) 
, DONE PRINTING

(98) b, (9)     , (50) 2, (10) 
, DONE PRINTING

(98) b, (9)     , (51) 3, (10) 
, DONE PRINTING

(98) b, (9)     , (52) 4, (10) 
, DONE PRINTING
```

Comment: Okay so it looks like it was printing spaces. That being said, how to I make sure they are tabs in my data.txt file, if I did use tabs when I made it?

Comment: It depends on your platform and editor.   Are you on a Unix-like system using `vim`, or something else?